# Need information about manifest xml setting for GameService.ane from distriqt

Tags: distriqt

Is anybody know how to get these infos:

```
YOUR_APPLICATION_IDENTIFIER
CONTAINER_IDENTIFIER
KEYCHAIN_ACCESS_GROUPS
YOUR_BUNDLE_ID
YOUR_GOOGLE_PLAYSERVICES_CLIENTID
```

for iOS manifest file (adobe air app)

[Link to sample here](https://gist.github.com/marchbold/d81578717dea0d2b7c2f)

Comment: Have you checked out the getting started guide? It has details on how to setup your application: http://airnativeextensions.com/extension/com.distriqt.GameServices#get-started

Comment: Sure. But one thing help me not on this page: http://airnativeextensions.com/extension/com.distriqt.GameServices#get-started , but here: https://github.com/distriqt/ANE-GameServices/blob/master/example/starling/src/TestGameServices-app.xml